# COM port redirect wont show up on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, terminal-server, serial

I can't get serial COM port devices to show up on Windows Server 2012 R2 via RDP.

I am having no issue with redirected printers, but when it comes to serial COM devices, they just wont show up.

I have disabled "Do not allow COM port redirection" on both the client and server

I have made sure the drivers are installed on the server.
I have enabled "Ports" on the RDP connection window.

So I am not sure what else I need to do in order for this to work.

I am trying from a Windows 8.1 client and a Windows Server 2012 R2 server

Comment: You can use this command to confirm that the COM ports are or aren't redirected: `change port /query`

Comment: I ran that command and I got this ```C:\Users\Administrator>change port /query
AUX = \DosDevices\COM1
COM1 = \Device\Serial0
COM3 = \Device\RdpDrPort\;COM3:2\tsclient\COM3```
Yet device manager only shows COM1

Comment: The redirection seems to be OK then.
What happens when you try to use COM3 in your application ? I'm not sure that the redirected ports will show up in the device manager